# How to save the previewed (Zoomed) image as Photo using AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, swift3, avcapture

So, I've magnet out how to make a Zoom Effect with CATransform3DMakeScale(2.4, 2.4, 2.4) but now I have problems trying to save the Zoome preview Message (code as I do Zooming):

```
 // init camera device
    let captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice? = initCaptureDevice()
    print("camera was initialized")
    // Prepare output
    initOutput()
    if (captureDevice != nil) {
        let deviceInput : AVCaptureInput? = initInputDevice(captureDevice: captureDevice!)
        if (deviceInput != nil) {
            initSession(deviceInput: deviceInput!)
            // Preview Size
            let previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session)
            previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
            previewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(2.4, 2.4, 2.4)
             imagePreviewScale = previewLayer.contentsScale
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            self.session?.startRunning()
```

Now i tried to save the previewed Zoomed image like so:

```
 let videoConnection : AVCaptureConnection? = self.imageOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if (videoConnection != nil) {

        videoConnection?.videoScaleAndCropFactor = imagePreviewScale

        self.imageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
            if (imageDataSampleBuffer != nil) {
                                    // Capture JPEG

                let imageData : NSData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer) as NSData
                // JPEG
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
```

and added the line

```
 imagePreviewScale = previewLayer.contentsScale
```

But still nothing happens, please anyone can tell me how to save The Exactly Zoomed picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `previewLayer.contentsScale` is 1, so you're setting `videoScaleAndCropFactor` to 1.

You need to set it to

```
videoConnection?.videoScaleAndCropFactor = 2.4
```